# assign list of string to a taggable field

Tags: python, django, django-models, tagging, django-tagging

I have a list  **s** where,

```
s = 'The name of my country is Bangladesh'
```

I converted the string into list of strings like below:

```
ss = s.split()
```

Again, in my database model I have a field **keywords**

```
keywords = TaggableManager(_('keywords'), blank=True, help_text=keywords_help_text)
```

I want to assign the list of string **ss** to the field keywords. I tried below:

```
keywords = ss
```

but I got error. I want to assign the list of string to my taggfield.

Comment: "I got error" doesn't tell anyone anywhere near enough to be able to give you meaningful help. Kindly explain (by including it in your post) what error message you got.

Comment: Do you really want to use "the", "of", "my" and "is" as keywords?

Comment: Yap. Every single string @garnertb

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are doing it the wrong way.

You have some class in which you have this keyword field which is efffectively a many to many relationship with another model (something like 'Tags')

How you use it is:

lets say the class is Fruits then you will have to take the instance of that class say Mango(the object you want to create keywords for)

Then you use:

```
Mango.keywords.add(ss)
```

or

```
self.keywords.add(ss)
```